# Does $(A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D)=(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap D)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$ be nonempty sets.

Does $(A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D)=(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap D)$?

It seems to be true by looking at Venn diagram, but I'm getting mixed up with the proof.

Comment: Let $B=C=A^c$ the complement of $A$ and let $D=A$. Is it true?

Comment: An exhaustive search for a counterexample only needs to consider 16 possible cases. One of those (at least) is a counterexample. See my answer below.

Comment: It is not hard to show that the right-hand side is a subset of the left-hand side. However, if you draw a Venn Diagram, you will see that "in general" the left-hand side has extra stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Suppose $A=D=\emptyset$. Then $(A\cup B)\cap (C\cup D)=B\cap C$, but $(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap D)=\emptyset$.

This is still false if you require the sets to be nonempty. Let $A=D=\{0\}$. Then the first set is $(B\cap C)\cup \{0\}$ and the second is at most $\{0\}$, which are not equal in general.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say nonempty sets. I will edit the question.

Comment: @GradEwnder It doesn't matter. Let $A=D=\{0\}$. Then the first set is $(B\cap C)\cup \{0\}$ and the second is $\{0\}$.

Comment: @AlexBecker:  the second can even be empty if $0 \not \in B$, for example.

Comment: @RossMillikan Good point.

Answer (score 6):

You could fill in this whole truth table.  If there is **one row** in which the last two columns disagree, then that answers your question.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
x\in A & x\in B & x\in C & x\in D & x\in(A\cup B)\cap(C\cup D) & x\in(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap D)  \\
\hline
T & T & T & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
T & T & T & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
T & T & f & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
T & f & T & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & T & T & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
T & T & f & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
T & f & T & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & T & T & f & T & f \\
T & f & f & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & T & f & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & f & T & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
T & f & f & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & T & f & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & f & T & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & f & f & T & \cdots & \cdots \\
f & f & f & f & \cdots & \cdots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$